# $X$ and $Y$ are schemes of finite type over $S$, then $X \times_S Y$ is of finite type over $S$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $X$ and $Y$ are schemes of finite type over $S$, then $X \times_S Y$ is of finite type over $S$. I was reading a solution but it's not complete.

**Attempt of proof**

Let $f:X\to S$ and $g:Y\to S$ be the corresponding morphisms of finite type. Let $\pi_Y: X \times_S Y \to Y$ be the projection to $Y$.

Consider the compositions:

$$ X \times_S Y \xrightarrow{\pi_Y}  Y \xrightarrow{g} S $$

Recall that compositions between morphisms of finite type is again of finite type. It's enough to show that $\pi_Y$ is of finite type.

I read that $\pi_Y$ is of finite type because that $f$ is of finite type but I don't know how to prove this implication

Comment: $\pi_Y\colon X \times_S Y \to Y$ is the base extension of the map $f\colon X \to S$ via the map $g \colon Y \to S$. So $\pi_Y$ is of finite type by Hartshorne Exc. II.3.13(d).

Comment: It's straightforward to prove this directly. Take a cover of $X$ and of $Y$, then relate this to a cover of $X\times_S Y$ and reduce to the case that $X,Y$ are affine. Then use that the product of affines is a spectrum of tensor products so the question is reduced to a simple problem from algebra.